# CMS Made Simple - adding extra editing fields to Global Content Blocks possible

Tags: content-management-system, cmsmadesimple

I am spoiled in using Advanced Custom Fields for wordpress. But now I am using CMS Made Simple since the client has it.

I have the Global Content Block which suits me nicely – but there is only one field - and I would like to have multiple fields there to make it more functional.

Is there any way to do this, or is there a better module to install for making this?

Thank you. I have googled, but not found my way through on this one.

Comment: There probably is a better way but without knowing what your goal is, it's difficult to guide. What sort of fields? How is this info to be displayed on the site? Perhaps look at **ListIt2** which is a great way of editor entering info and website displaying lists of multi-field items in any way.

Comment: You are right. For me simple textfields would be sufficient.

[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1151346/jobb/2.%20hejamartin/bosum/skiss-aktiv.jpg)

The 5 "news" on the right side would be needed to be added easily. One header each, as well as rich body content, and a textfield for adding in an external link.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ListIt2 module would be a great choice for this layout. ListIt2 enables you to show a complex design within the website but, in the back end, have the editor presented with a simple list structure in which he can edit text and re-order items. And you can easily add fields for images and text.

Check out the module at
http://dev.cmsmadesimple.org/projects/listit2